# Inflate an Image Using CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a div with a background image that I would like to inflate using CSS3 webkit-keyframes.

I tried animating using `background-size`, but it looks like CSS3 (or at least Safari webkit) doesn't animate `background-size`.

How can I rewrite this code to get the same effect (i.e. I would like the image to inflate from the center of the div)?

Some simple vanilla javascript would also be okay, but I'd prefer a pure-CSS solution.

HTML:

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div#image
{
    background: url('../img/image.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 125px;
    height: 252px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    top: 260px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.35, 1.0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-name: pop_image;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pop_image
{
    0% {background-size: 0%;}
    25% {background-size: 0%;}
    48% {background-size: 100%;}
    100% {background-size: 100%;}
}
```

Edit:

I also tried animating on `-webkit-transform: scale()`, but that didn't work either.

Edit 2:

So, animating on `-webkit-transform: scale()` worked, I just needed to refresh my browser.

Here is the CSS3 keyframe:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pop_keys
{
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0,0);}
    25% {-webkit-transform: scale(0,0);}
    48% {-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css. `scale` and animate the images to scale up:

http://jsfiddle.net/DvVug/1/

**EDIT:**

Updated so the image doesn't 'jump' back to original size